# Tzom Gedalya vs. Taanis Esther

Tags: words, names, fast-days

Why is Tzom Gedalya known as Tzom Gedalya and Taanis Esther as Taanis Esther. Why not Taanis Gedalya or Tzom Esther?

Comment: one discussion with an answer regarding the distinction http://www.fresh.co.il/vBulletin/showthread.php?t=551149

Comment: It often is referred to as Tzom Esther in classical sources.

Comment: more specifically Tzom Megillah, in Siddur Rasag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tzom* is the word used most often in Biblical Hebrew to mean "fast" (such as in Isaiah in Esther); the word *Taanis* doesn't appear until the Book of Ezra, which was later (about two hundred years after Isaiah).

Hence, Tzom Gedalya is called *Tzom* because it is mentioned in Tanakh ([Zechariah 8:19](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16212/jewish/Chapter-8.htm#v=19)), while Taanis Esther uses the more modern term *Taanis* because it was established much later (after the closing of the Talmud in the 5th century CE).

Comment: Is this your own guess?

Comment: Yes, but it seems pretty logical.

Comment: @Ypnypn FYI Taanis is mentioned in                             [Ezra 9:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16506) and Tzom is mentioned in [Esther eg 4:3 and 9:31](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16477).

Comment: Ok but Ezra is about the same time as Esther.

Comment: Isn't the root in early Biblical Hebrew that means fast ענה (the root of תענית)? The root צומ is a later usage.

Comment: @DoubleAA: The root ענה is older, but it means "afflict" in any sense. The derivation תענית, which refers specifically to fasting, came much later.

Comment: What about its usage in Lev23?

Comment: It's not clear that it means refraining from eating; the Talmud derives that from "וְהַאֲבַדְתִּי אֶת הַנֶּפֶשׁ". Also the word teaches about marital relations (although that may be an asmachtah)

Comment: @Ypnypn That is one possible derivation in the Talmud. Furthermore, what evidence do you have that the instance in Ezra doesn't include all the inuyim as well? Finally, if anything 3 Tishrei should be Taanit because the inuyim can apply, whereas 13 Adar is a commemoration of a solely food related event.

Comment: I don't know what the instance in Ezra refers to, but in Biblical Hebrew ענה meant any affliction, whereas צומ meant abstaining from food. Later, ענה started being used as synonym for צומ.